# Caliburn.Micro's WindowManager.ShowPopup with settings

Tags: wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

Ultimately I would like to animate a sliding popup from the system tray using Caliburn.Micro and WPF.

So far I am able to show my popup using this code:

```
WindowManager.ShowPopup(new PopupViewModel());
```

But this will show the popup where my current mouse position is. It appears that the command accepts settings, but some of them don't seem to play nicely.

```
dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();
settings.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
settings.Top = 0;
WindowManager.ShowPopup(new PopupViewModel(), null, settings);
```

Does not put the popup at the top of the screen, WindowStartupLocation.Center also does not center the popup. However, settings.Width and settings.Height seem to work. Any ideas? I ultimately want to put the icon in the bottom right corner near the system tray. And THEN - I would like to animate a slide up.

Answer (score 1):

the reason is that for showing a popup caliburn creates a Wpf Popup, that does not accept properties like "WindowStartupLocation".
You should instead use properties of Popup object.
Hear is an example:

```
settings.Width = 200;
settings.PopupAnimation = PopupAnimation.Fade;
settings.Placement = PlacementMode.Absolute;
settings.HorizontalOffset = SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth / 2 - 100;
settings.VerticalOffset = SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight / 2 - 50;
```